React causes unnecessary rerenders
I am creating a chat app and have some problems while trying to implement the link preview (when you send a link, I want to load the title and image from the url). From the code below you can see that i'm mapping through every "text message" in text array and rendering a component called ChatMessage. Each ChatMessage component represents a message from the user in the group. Once I open the chat, messages get loaded and links get previewed as well. The problem I'm having is that on each message I send or receive from another user, all ChatMessage components get rerendered and consequently all links get previewed again (data is fetched from urls again, which causes links to show urls for a split second and then the loaded data once it's loaded from useEffect).
How can I prevent that? How can I load the links only once and not every time I get a new message or send one by myself? Below is the code.
------- Chat.jsx ---------
{members.length > 0 && text.map((m, index) => { return <ChatMessage key={index} text={text} m={m} index={index} isMessageSending={isMessageSending} /> })}

--------ChatMessage.jsx ---------
export const ChatMessage = memo(({ text, m, index, isMessageSending }) => {
    // "m" prop is a message object containing message and timestamp when it was sent.
    // "text" prop is all messages in a chat
    const { usersRef } = useContext(PageContext);
    const [userMessageData, setUserMessageData] = useState({});
    const isSentByMe = m.sentBy === auth.currentUser.uid;
    const [linkData, setLinkData] = useState({});

    // this useEffect is supposed to be called when the m.message changes. Why does it get called again when i send a new message? Each message represents this component so it shouldn't be "related" to other messages.
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!m.message) return;

        let foo = async () => {

            if (isValidUrl(m.message)) {
                const data = await fetchDataFromLink(m.message);
                setLinkData(data.result);
            } else {
                setLinkData({});
            }
        }
        foo();
    }, [m.message]);

    return (
        <div> ... </div>
    )

I tried using memo and useCallback for loading the preview of a link but it still kept rerendering once I hit a send message button.

A ChatMessage's props contains the text prop,  which is an array of all messages in a chat. When you send a message, the text array is updated to include that new message in its list, and as such all dependents of this prop will be re-rendered. In this case, that would be every single ChatMessage component, as in your text.map(..) you pass in the live text as a prop to each.
The memo function's intention is to preserve calculation. However, when its component's props are changed, it will not memoize, as semantically that prop may include "updated data" that may need to be reflected in its component, and thus the component must be re-rendered (re-calculated), and then memoized using those new conditions. memo will then not re-render if the props henceforth remain unchanged.
From the code snippet provided, the text prop appears to be unused in each ChatMessage, and as such the simple solution would be to remove it entirely from the props list and not pass it in.
If ChatMessage does use data in the text prop in what isn't shown in the code, then perhaps see if the data you require could be separated from the text prop at some memoized point or in a constant manner. The core issue stems in that when providing each ChatMessage with a text prop, you are making them privy to the entire chat's live data, rather than being a self-contained component. If a ChatMessage doesn't require broadcast of new chats that follow it, or perhaps even prior chats, then it should hopefully follow naturally for you to separate the required data from texts that you may be using for each ChatMessage.

tbh im not sure if my answer helps, as it assumes a re-render == re-fetch of the link, but since you did set a dependency array, that as far as I can see from the snippet has nothing to do with text (only m), the changing text prop, while still causing possibly unnecessary re-renders, shouldn't trigger this useEffect that re-fetches the link. Lmk tho if it helped, i'll be thinking on this
